# How do I CC someone when an order is placed?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am using Ubercart with Drupal.

How do I CC someone when an order is placed? I will probably have to modify the code somewhere  because it should only happen under a certain theme, but I'm not sure where to even edit this.

Comment: I didn't vote it down but I'd guess it was because there's no evidence of research/code in your question. Using the conditional actions module (as you have done) is the correct way to do this either way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to admin/store/ca and created an action. I used the products as a condition and it works.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use the `hook_mail_alter()` in a small stub module.
This hook will let you add add to the email generated by another module.
You will need to dig into the ubercart code to find the specific `$mailkey` for the email you want to change.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6

```
function myhack_mail_alter(&$message)
{
    if ($message['id'] == 'the ubercart mail key')
    {
        //$message['headers']['Bcc'] = 'myemail@example.com';     
        $message['headers']['cc'] = 'myemail@example.com';      
    }
}
```

One way to find the message key is to add the following to your function, then have the site send the email. This function will dump the keys to the `dblog`.

```
watchdog('MailKey', $message['id'], {}, WATCHDOG_INFO);
```